# ActionBarCompat + NavigationDrawerFragment doesnt work on android 4.0 and 4.1

Tags: android, android-studio, navigation-drawer, android-actionbar-compat

Very strange problem! 
I created a new project through new project wizard in android studio. I chose to include support libraries for GridLayout, Fragments, NavigationDrawer and ActionBar. In next step I chose BlankActivity Template with NavigationDrawer navigation. Wizard nicely created my project and build it without any problem.

Problem is this, when you try to run it, it works fine on Android 4.3, 4.2 and 2.3.3 but it crashes on 4.0 and 4.1.

Stack trace:

```
10-30 13:11:31.024    2136-2136/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.navdrawer/com.navdrawer.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:256)
        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1867)
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superSetContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:208)
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:111)
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:76)
        at com.navdrawer.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:37)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.navdrawer.MainActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(MainActivity.java:82)
        at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2476)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:224)
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superOnCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:224)
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:141)
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:199)
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS$WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:280)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:393)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.invalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:747)
        at android.app.Activity.invalidateOptionsMenu(Activity.java:2595)
        at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompatHoneycomb.invalidateOptionsMenu(ActivityCompatHoneycomb.java:29)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(FragmentActivity.java:633)
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:170)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.setHasOptionsMenu(Fragment.java:781)
        at com.navdrawer.NavigationDrawerFragment.onCreate(NavigationDrawerFragment.java:82)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:1455)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:893)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1082)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1184)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:285)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:676)
... 24 mo
```

This is the onCreateOptionsMenu in fragment

```
 public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        // If the drawer is open, show the global app actions in the action bar. See also
        // showGlobalContextActionBar, which controls the top-left area of the action bar.
        if (mDrawerLayout != null && isDrawerOpen()) {
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.global, menu);
            showGlobalContextActionBar();
        }
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }
```

This one is in the MainActivity

```
 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
            // Only show items in the action bar relevant to this screen
            // if the drawer is not showing. Otherwise, let the drawer
            // decide what to show in the action bar.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            restoreActionBar();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the snippet `onCreateOptionsMenu()` as a `LayoutInflater` remains null inside it?

Comment: Have you updated to the latest Android Support Library v18? To be safe, you can use [Sherlock ActionBar](http://actionbarsherlock.com/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9886523/how-to-create-a-android-app-with-ics-ui-that-works-with-gingerbread-and-froyo

Comment: Here you go give it a try.... I think that should not be problem, i believe its a bug in ActionBarActivity class from ActionbarCompat support library

Comment: I used Sherlock many times and I m satisfied more or less, now I am researching posibilities with ActionBarCompat library

Comment: It complains "Binary XML file line #24" of either menu's or activity's XML file.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just ran into this same exact issue. EXACT ISSUE.

The issue is that `setHasOptionsMenu(true);` is called in `onCreate` instead of `onActivityCreated` in the Fragment. Seems like a bug in the Wizard if you ask me.

To solve this, move the `setHasOptionsMenu(true);` call from `onCreate()` to `onActivityCreated()`.

This will solve the problem. By the time the call gets to `Activity#onCreateOptionsMenu` the fragment instance will be instantiated.

Comment: more elegant answer than mine tnx!! why this works on 4.2 and 4.3... how did you figured out this

Comment: i fill up an issue for android studio https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61769

Answer (score 4):

I resolved problem. Stack trace was tottally missleading to me...

Problem was as eee suggested in onCreateOptionsMenu() in activity...

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
            // Only show items in the action bar relevant to this screen
            // if the drawer is not showing. Otherwise, let the drawer
            // decide what to show in the action bar.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            restoreActionBar();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

somehow only on Android 4.1 and 4.0 `mNavigationDrawerFragment` is null although it's initialized in `onCreate()` so i put this

```
if(mNavigationDrawerFragment == null )
            mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
                    getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
```

in both `onCreate()` and in `onCreateOptionsMenu()` method

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem by just putting a try catch block for the

```
setHasOptionsMenu(true);
```

As Donn Felker explained the exception is arising due to call before the activity is created.
Handling this exception can solve the problem.